# Is there a way to change the priority of an async operation before it executes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a save/load system for a game in Unity, and I have run into an issue.

the save system currently saves all open scenes to the file's list upon saving.

When loading, i.e upon the player's death in-game, the scenes are all loaded asynchronously from a list that is pulled from the file.

The problem I'm experiencing is that due to unity needing to have at least one scene loaded at all times, I end up with multiple instances of whatever scenes were already loaded. The solution I have come up with thus far is to put all loaded scenes in a list and then unload them immediately after the save-file scenes have loaded, but therein lies the issue:

I have no idea how to ensure that the unload operations happen *after* the load operations.

I have searched google only to find very few results on this; aside from unity's rather unhelpful documentation that states that async operations have a `.priority` property, but does not give examples how to change it before the async starts to actually run, only that the priority has no effect after it starts.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-priority.html

here is a slimmed-down and commented version of my code:

```cs
List<AsyncOperation> _asyncs = new list<AsyncOperation>();
List<String> _scenesFromLoadedSaveFile = new List<string>();

//pretend there is something here which gets all the loaded scenes 
//and puts them in _listOfAlreadyLoadedScenes. I have that in my real code.

foreach(string _sceneToUnload in _listOfAlreadyLoadedScenes)
{
    //this is where i need help.
    //how do i set the priority of this before it runs here?
    _asyncs.add(SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(_sceneToUnload)); 
}

foreach(string _sceneToLoad in _scenesFromLoadedSaveFile)
{
    _asyncs.add(Scenemanager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneToLoad));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `AsyncOperation unload = SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(_sceneToUnload); unload.priority = 0; _asyncs.add(unload);` and `AsyncOperation load = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneToLoad); load.priority = 999; _asyncs.add(load);` ?

Comment: I have not, but may as well try. The reason i haven't is because of the unity documentation's statement that "Once an operation has been started on the background thread, changing the priority will have no effect anymore." wouldn't that mean that by the time the priority is set in this manner, the async op will already be running?

Comment: Update:  i tried it and this is exactly what happens. the priority is ignored due to the fact that the async operation is started before the priority is assigned.

Comment: If you're calling this code in a coroutine on the main thread, it shouldn't begin on a background thread until control flow leaves the current frame on the main thread. Is this code within a coroutine?

Comment: yes. and yet; for some reason which I guess I don't understand, I still have duplicate scenes that are never unloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that `priority` only affects the order that asynchronous operations are resumed each frame, not necessarily that one will wait for another's completion. This would prevent the unloading calls from properly beginning when it's their turn to be called.

So, instead, it may be better to establish a hard sequencing of performing all of the loading and waiting for that to be completed before the unloading commences:

```
List<AsyncOperation> _asyncs = new list<AsyncOperation>();
List<String> _scenesFromLoadedSaveFile = new List<string>();

IEnumerator DoSceneReload() 
{
    // set _listOfAlreadyLoadedScenes here

    _asyncs.Clear();

    foreach(string _sceneToLoad in _scenesFromLoadedSaveFile)
    {
        _asyncs.add(Scenemanager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneToLoad));
    }

    // wait for every scene to load
    foreach(AsyncOperation ao in _asyncs)
    {
        yield return ao; 
    }

    _asyncs.Clear();


    // unload every scene asynchronously 
    foreach(string _sceneToUnload in _listOfAlreadyLoadedScenes)
    {
        _asyncs.add(SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(_sceneToUnload)); 
    }

    MethodToCallOnAllUnloadsBeginning();

    // If you want to, you could then wait for every scene to load 
    // before performing some final task
    foreach(AsyncOperation ao in _asyncs)
    {
        yield return ao; 
    }

    MethodToCallOnAllUnloadsComplete();

}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you! now all I need to do is figure out some nuances in my code that are causing issues unrelated to this one.